# n-1 async callback implementation

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm re writing an IOS app in android. It's a task I've set to try and learn android.
In android I've being learning about different async messaging options. What I have found so far are:

```
Callbacks
Broadcasts
Message Handlers
```

I'm trying to decide which approach is best to suit my purposes. In my IOS application I have 10 screen objects and 1 coordinator object. This is my n-1.

The way my ios currently works is my screen object calls a work method in my coordinator passing itself as a delegate. The coordinator performs some async work and calls various methods on the delegate when the job is done : completed / failed with reason etc.

Multiple screen objects can request work to be done at the same time.

So far my feeling that the callback / message handler approaches in android is more like a 1-1 relationship.

I'm leaning towards using the local broadcast manager. This does seem more like NSNotification than delegate methods but seems made for n-1 relationships.

Is the broadcast manager the best way to achieve n - 1 async work ?

Also are my assumption about the 1-1 relationship of callbacks and handlers correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use the broadcasts like NSNotification, but I would generally use broadcasts to message between different parts of my App, for example to communicate between a Service and an Activity, rather than within a specific part.

I don't see why you can't do exactly what you do in iOS on android as well. You would have a protocol in iOS defining what functions to call, and you can do the same in Java/Android by using interfaces.

In iOS you would have something like:

```
doStuffWithObject:(NSObject<SpecialStuff> *)object {}
```

while in Java you would have:

```
doStuffWithObject(SpecialStuff object) {}
```

with SpecialStuff being your protocol or interface.
Because you don't have `performSelectorOnBackground` in android its a bit more work. Either use Timers, perhaps a separate Thread in combination with Handlers or use [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) depending on what serves you best and how big the asynchronous task is.

ASyncTask is definitely worth looking into.

---

You could of course also make use of [Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html) and [Observable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html).

A simple example with an handler and a timer that notifies its listeners of a new time every second (note that the handler is created on the main thread in this case, such that you can send messages back similar to using `performSelectorOnMainThread` in iOS):

```
    class SomeExample {

    private final ArrayList<TimeListener> timeListeners;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final TimeUpdateRunnable timeUpdateRunnable = new TimeUpdateRunnable();

    public SomeExampleView {

        timeListeners = new ArrayList<TimeListener>();

        updateTimer = new Timer("General Update Timer");

        TimeUpdateTask timeUpdateTask = new TimeUpdateTask();
        updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeUpdateTask, (60 * 1000) -   (System.currentTimeMillis() % (60 * 1000)), 60 * 1000);
    }

    public void addTimeListener(TimeListener timeListener) {
        timeListeners.add(timeListener);
    }

    public boolean removeTimeListener(TimeListener timeListener) {
        return timeListeners.remove(timeListener);
    }


    class TimeUpdateTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(timeUpdateRunnable);
        }
    }

    private class TimeUpdateRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            for (TimeListener timeListener : timeListeners) {
                timeListener.onTimeUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my listener interface which is similar to `Observer`

```
public interface TimeListener {
    void onTimeUpdate(long time);
}
```

Comment: this answer removes a lot of doubt for me. Thanks for the effort